# Failed to load module script with Chart.js: MIME type of "text/html"

Tags: javascript, chart.js, mime-types

I can't resolve the error " Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

I'm trying to import the Chart.js library in the 'main.js' file, which will be called in 'index.html' as:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>my Chart</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
import Chart from "./node_modules/chart.js/auto";

const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [...Array(10).keys()],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'myChart',
      data: [10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: { type: 'logarithmic'}
    }
  }

});
```

According to the documentation, you normally call the script directly in the html document with:
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>`
However, I installed the library with `npm install chart.js` and `npm install chartjs-plugin-zoom`  as I need to add other features, like plugins, which will be imported into 'main.js' as `import zoomPlugin from "./node_modules/chartjs-plugin-zoom";`...
The 'main.js' and 'index.html' files are in the same directory as 'node_modules'.

The error disappears when deleting the line `import Chart from "./node_modules/chart.js/auto";` from 'main.js' and calling the script directly through `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>`, however I can't use 'zoomPlugin' from `import zoomPlugin from "./node_modules/chartjs-plugin-zoom";` since a MIME type error occurs on this import as well.

What could be causing the 'MIME type' error?

Answer (score 0):

Only JavaScript (and [JSON](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-modules)) modules can be imported.

The URL `./node_modules/chart.js/auto` points to an HTML document, not a JavaScript module.

Glancing at the directory structure when I install that module from npm, `auto` is a directory, not a JavaScript module. Presumably your HTTP server is generating an HTML document containing a directory listing.

Likewise, `"./node_modules/chartjs-plugin-zoom` will also be a directory listing. The node_modules directory contains *only* directories (one per installed module).

Comment: From what I saw in 'node_modules', 'chart.js/auto' is indeed a directory with .js files inside. I tried `import Chart from "./node_modules/chart.js";` without success since 'chart.js' is also a directory...

Comment: The documentation says 'Chart.js is tree-shakeable, so it is necessary to import and register the controllers, elements, scales and plugins you are going to use'. But I don't know the correct way to import 'Chart' and 'zoomPlugin'...

Comment: You have to give the URL to the JS file you want to import. I'm not going to search through the directories of every package you want to use to find JS files that are ECMAScript modules. You can do that yourself.

Comment: The problem is that the documentation suggests `import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';` and then `const chart = new Chart(ctx, {type: 'line', date: date,});`... so there's no reason why 'Chart' doesn't run...

Comment: Do you mean [this documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html)? In particular the section marked “Bundlers”? You are not using a bundler, you are loading the JS directly. You need, as I have said several times already, to use the URL to the JS module.

Comment: Yes, I had to use a solution with the `webpack` module because I didn't know which javascript file to import either from the library or from the `chartjs-plugin-zoom` plugin...